# msal://redirect not working in custom app

Tags: javascript, azure, electron, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am creating a electron based app where I ask the user to login to microsoft. When logging in I get the error of `Failed to load URL; msal://redirect with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. I tried the quickstart project given by azure and it worked even with msal://redirect. I am confused as I have also taken the tutorial code and it doesnt work in this custom project. Here is my code:

```
const MSAL_CONFIG = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "id",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    },
};

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(MSAL_CONFIG);
// The redirect URI you setup during app registration with a custom file protocol "msal"
const redirectUri = "msal://redirect";

const cryptoProvider = new CryptoProvider();

const pkceCodes = {
    challengeMethod: "S256", // Use SHA256 Algorithm
    verifier: "", // Generate a code verifier for the Auth Code Request first
    challenge: "" // Generate a code challenge from the previously generated code verifier
};

/**
 * Starts an interactive token request
 * @param {object} authWindow: Electron window object
 * @param {object} tokenRequest: token request object with scopes
 */
async function getTokenInteractive(authWindow, tokenRequest) {

    /**
     * Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) Setup
     *
     * MSAL enables PKCE in the Authorization Code Grant Flow by including the codeChallenge and codeChallengeMethod
     * parameters in the request passed into getAuthCodeUrl() API, as well as the codeVerifier parameter in the
     * second leg (acquireTokenByCode() API).
     */

    const {verifier, challenge} = await cryptoProvider.generatePkceCodes();

    pkceCodes.verifier = verifier;
    pkceCodes.challenge = challenge;

    const authCodeUrlParams = {
        redirectUri: redirectUri,
        scopes: tokenRequest.scopes,
        codeChallenge: pkceCodes.challenge, // PKCE Code Challenge
        codeChallengeMethod: pkceCodes.challengeMethod // PKCE Code Challenge Method
    };

    const authCodeUrl = await pca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParams);

    // register the custom file protocol in redirect URI
    protocol.registerFileProtocol(redirectUri.split(":")[0], (req, callback) => {
        const requestUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
        callback(path.normalize(`${__dirname}/${requestUrl.path}`));
    });

    const authCode = await listenForAuthCode(authCodeUrl, authWindow); // see below

    const authResponse = await pca.acquireTokenByCode({
        redirectUri: redirectUri,
        scopes: tokenRequest.scopes,
        code: authCode,
        codeVerifier: pkceCodes.verifier // PKCE Code Verifier
    });

    return authResponse;
}

/**
 * Listens for auth code response from Azure AD
 * @param {string} navigateUrl: URL where auth code response is parsed
 * @param {object} authWindow: Electron window object
 */
async function listenForAuthCode(navigateUrl, authWindow) {

    authWindow.loadURL(navigateUrl);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        authWindow.webContents.on('will-redirect', (event, responseUrl) => {
            try {
                const parsedUrl = new URL(responseUrl);
                const authCode = parsedUrl.searchParams.get('code');
                resolve(authCode);
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}

exports.getTokenInteractive = getTokenInteractive;
```